# value too long for type character varying(255) for length 100000

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am using Spring Data JPA and my column definition is

```
@Column(length = 100000)
private String description;
```

And in the payload, I am using description having character count `20000`. But its still throwing

> ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)`

If `100000` is not enough to hold character of length `20000` how is the error `varying(255)` however in the physical database table I can see `character varying(100000)` in table definition.  [image: database column]

Getting same error even for the `Text Type` using text of `length 1990` only

```
   2021-08-23 17:48:24.727  WARN 21044 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22001
   2021-08-23 17:48:24.727 ERROR 21044 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
   2021-08-23 17:48:24.733 ERROR 21044 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure           : HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred
```

Comment: If you can see the column to be defined as `varchar(10000)` and you get the error message from your Java code, then your Java code  is connecting to a different database where that column has a different definition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is not the case because its working on `text` but since `100000` would be sufficient enough for me i am interested using this one.

Comment: There is no performance or storage advantage having `varchar(10000)` over `text`. But if Postgres complains about the length, then I am inclined to believe Postgres that the column is defined as `varchar(255)` - the error message is more than obvious you are trying to store more than 255 characters in a column defined with that maximum.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not only the storage advantage but i need to change my java code to fetch data back from database i.e deserialization which i don't want and `varchar(255)` is the default one i was expecting too long for the type `varchar(100000)`

Comment: Please post the errror as it appears in the postgresql log complete with all comments etc, and the table definition (or psql \dt output)

Comment: @Jasen image already attached as evidence.

Comment: You have not shown the table schema as described in Postgres, please do so as update to your question.

Comment: I am not saying that this did not happen. I am asking exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2):

**Sure, your java code run an sql statement where an varchar(255) column is overupdated with more than 255 length string.**

- Perhaps you use Hibernate Envers
- Perhaps there is some trigger function on the table
- Perhaps you is connected other db
- Perhaps others

First log the sql statement with values.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

You could run the sql statement to your db.

- If works than you connect other db
- If not, then you can solve problem on db side.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is on the database because the varchar column in PostgreSQL db as i know accept 255 char, change the character varying or character column to be a text column type instead
(Since Postgres 9.2, sometimes text is not used initially)

`ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN description TYPE text;`

Comment: The question is about Postgres not MySQL. Either change you answer to one that is relevant or delete it.

Comment: yes i'm sorry i didn't pay attention but in this case it's the same as postgresql also uses 255

Comment: No that is not true either. In Postgres `varchar` without a length specifier is equal to `text` and the string stored can max to ~1GB in size. As example: `create table varchar_test(var_fld varchar(1000));  var_fld | character varying(1000)`.

Comment: Since Postgres 9.2, sometimes text is not used initially