# value too long for type character varying(255) for data_type TEXT in postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have already asked [at there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833643/value-too-long-for-type-character-varying255-for-length-100000). Here is the column of entity class

```
  @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
  private String description;
```

But still getting error

```
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
... 108 common frames omitted
```

[image]

I tried with something like

```
@Column(name="description", columnDefinition="TEXT") 
@Lob 
private String description;
```

And it is creating similar data_type as in image but i am not getting any exception in save because `56422` stored in the table instead of large text .Getting error while pulling the record from `DB`. I am using `spring-data JPA`. Still struggling with relatively large text to store in DB and get back from DB.

```
 Could not write JSON: Unable to access lob stream; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to access lob stream (through reference chain
```

Here is what pgAdmin is showing the DDL script

```
 CREATE TABLE public.detail
 (
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('detail_id_seq'::regclass),
  department character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  description character varying(100000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  employee_details character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  CONSTRAINT detail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
 WITH (
 OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.detail 
OWNER to postgres;
```

With

```
@Column(length = 100000)
private String description;
```

Comment: How do you get the LOB from the ResultSet?

Comment: @JoopEggen i want to store large text only `LOB` is what i tried after visiting similar questions but this is not my requirement .

Comment: Same request as in your previous question. Add to your question the table schema as found in Postgres, e.g. log in via `psql` and do `\d <table_name>`. The error message is explicit the column you are trying to add the value to has a length restriction. You need to find which one that is in the database table without all the intervening code. This is how you are going to solve this.

Comment: Good, Clob should do. Fetch field best using ResultSet.getCharacterStream, a Reader. May be tied to that json thingy. Try things separately, in plain JDBC etcetera. I mainly responded due to the lack of details. Spring is vast

Comment: I'm confused where did `@Column(length = 100000) private String description;` come from? You started this with ` @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")  private String description;` My guess, based on some searching, is that `Spring` is confused about how to handle `TEXT`.

Comment: Post  your actual insert. Perhaps your issue in not getting the order of columns and order of values the same. I.E. you are inadvertently trying to insert value for `description` into either `department` or `employee_details` column.

Comment: @Belayer i am using spring data JPA and from UI payload its for description column only.I can see the text data for limited characters.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is why i linked my older question in this one. Actually i tried both data_type i.e text as well as 100000 for string but none of them is working.

Comment: Aah yes another ORM making the easy difficult. This is a Spring thing and beyond me.